# How can I press a keyboard key using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to allow my application to do things like hit the enter key or type words without actually touching the keys. Is this possible? How could I make an onscreen keyboard that lets you type into different applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question about "how to create an onscreen keyboard" is very broad as there are many valid approaches to this, not one single and canonical way to do it. Therefore, you probably won't get much help about the high-level details of this task unless you can narrow down specific issues.

However, as far as keyboard events are concerned, you would use the [Quartz Event Services API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent) to fabricate keyboard events. Specifically, you are looking for `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and `CGEventPost`.

```
// CGEvent functions
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

// kVK_* values
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

// press and release "abcd"
int virtualKeys[] = { kVK_ANSI_A, kVK_ANSI_B, kVK_ANSI_C, kVK_ANSI_D };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    // press the letter
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, virtualKeys[i], YES);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
    CFRelease(event);

    // wait .1 seconds
    usleep(100000);

    // release the letter
    event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, virtualKeys[i], NO);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
    CFRelease(event);
}
```

For capitals, you need to "press" `kVK_Shift` before the letter (and you need to release it as well).

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks! Can my application still execute these key commands even if it is in the background?

Comment: @ScottFitsimones, I'd have to try to tell you, and I'm not on a Mac right now, so it'll be up to you to find it out. :)

Comment: Could you explain how to press and hold this button? In your code you all the time press down and up. I want to implement "longpress" for alt (option) key